# Reuse identifier in nib does not match the identifier used to register the nib

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift2, ibdesignable

I have a Framework/Module written in Swift which provides some custom controls with IBDesignable functionality.

Currently I am working on a control based on a CollectionView. The CollectionView and the custom CollectionViewCell are build in Nib files. To load the CollectionViewNib and add the Designable funcionality I use this [NibDesignable](https://github.com/mbogh/NibDesignable) class. After initalising the CollectionView I register the CollectionViewCell as following:

```
let cellIdentifier = "collectionViewCell"

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

private func setup() {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: bundle), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)
}
```

After adding my Framework as Embedded Binary to another app I can use my new custom CollectionView as expected, but unfortunately the Designable functionality isn´t working well, instead I get the following error message:

```
IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: 
The agent raised a "NSInternalInconsistencyException" exception: 
view reuse identifier in nib (ibCollectionViewCell) does not match the identifier used to register the nib (collectionViewCell)
```

As describe above my Control works in the Simulator and on my Phone, so no I don´t use different identifiers. I don´t know where XCode gets this 
**ibCollectionViewCell** identifier, but when I use it as identifier for my CollectionViewCell every thing works like a charm.

Any ideas where this identifier comes from and why XCode can´t load my custom CollectionViewCell with my own identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating from XCode 7 Beta 4 to Beta 5 the error was gone. So I assume there was something buggy in the previous version